# What is the error in following python code

Tags: python-2.7

```
import sys

def Hello(name):
   name = name + '!!!'
   print 'Hello' ,  name


def main():
    Hello(sys.argv[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonPractice\firstPython.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\pythonPractice\firstPython.py", line 9, in main
    Hello(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have also tried sys.argv[2] but error remains

Comment: Your code doesn't match the error. None of your lines contain `Hello(sys.argv[1])`.

Comment: I ran this script on my box (Python 2.7.3) and it worked without any problems. I'm a bit confused that your error message says sys.argv[1] is out of range but in your code you are using sys.argv[0]. Maybe you are running the wrong script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, I think the code you originally posted (with `Hello(sys.argv[0])`) is not what you actually have. It doesn't match the error, which states `sys.argv[1]`, so what you *probably* have is:

```
def main():
    Hello(sys.argv[1])
```

As to the error then, it's because you haven't provided an argument when running. You need to do so, such that `sys.argv[1]` exists:

```
python helloprog Pax
```

You would find a more robust `main` as:

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        Hello("whoever you are")
    else:
        Hello(sys.argv[1])
```

which will detect when you haven't provided an argument, and use a suitable default rather than raising an exception.

Comment: @darpan1118 the point is that you need to use the `if` and `else` blocks, just like in paxdiablo's answer. `sys.argv` is a python [list](http://doc.pyschools.com/html/list.html) (click for a great and short tutorial) and if you pass no [command line arguments](http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/command-line/#syntax) from the command line, you get your error, except you do the `if`-`else` block like above. If you run this from an IDE instead of a command line or terminal, you need to find a way to specify command line arguments (also called command line parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Have you used

```
sys.argv[0]
```

Since this returns a list , you may not have elements >1